# Big data CMS Full Text Search

Tags: content-management-system, full-text-search, bigdata

Currently I have an application where users upload the document ( pdfs/excel/word, few images). Looking a for Big-Data(Hadoop-MangoDB) solution where can

1. store thousands of pdf,word,excel files (as we are size is growing too)
2. Search image meta information
3. Full Text Search (Mostly Real-time)
4. Faster Retrieval

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

have a look at apache Hbase also..you may find it useful for your use case..it's a NOSQL database that runs on top of Hdfs and provides random real time read/write access..you can have a look at Apache Hive as well..although it is not for real time processing unlike Hbase, it provides a datawarehouse on top of a Hadoop cluster with SQL like interface..you can run Hive jobs in background and keep your data processed and ready to serve if you know the kind of processing in advance..it would be useful if you are coming from an SQL background.

Comment: i have used HBase ,hive  for my other project..  HBase is cloumn orienited can be used for indexing wth solr and hive is totaly irrelevant here. I m looking for a document oriented system like Mongo. But i dont like the idea stemming.

Comment: I haven't said that you should use Hive in place of Mongo or something like that. And there are several options if you want to go for a document oriented system like - Terrastore, Apache CouchDB, Amazon SimpleDB etc..you can choose one as per your convenience